# Amazon SNS CreatePlatformApplication returns error when reusing platform applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sns

I had code that was working that would create a new platform application for every message that went out. I thought that was wasteful so I tried to change the code to use `list_platform_applications` to get available applications and reuse the one that has the proper name (part of the `PlatformApplicationArn`).

This will work for several messages in a row when suddenly I'll get this error from `CreatePlatformApplication`:

> {"Error":{"Code":"InvalidParameter","Message":"Invalid parameter: This
>   endpoint is already registered with a different
>   token.","Type":"Sender"},"RequestId":"06bd3443-598e-5c06-9f5c-7f84349ea067"}

That doesn't even make sense. I'm creating an endpoint. I didn't pass one in. Is it really complaining about the endpoint it's returning.

According to the Amazon documentation:

> "The CreatePlatformEndpoint action is idempotent, so if the requester
>   already owns an endpoint with the same device token and attributes,
>   that endpoint's ARN is returned without creating a new endpoint."

So it seems to me, if there's an appropriate one it will be returned. Otherwise, create a brand new fresh one.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Im facing the same issue in creating GCM Android endpoints. Isn't a different endpoint is created for different token passed. ??

Comment: Also facing same issue. I am using node.js with a module called sns-mobile, which in turn wraps the aws-sdk. In the AWS SNS console I can see how new, "duplicate" endpoints (i.e. with the same token) are created until there are like 4 for each token; from then on creating new endpoints (for tokens which already exist) fail with above error. Really weird.

Answer (score 4):

Oh darn. I think I found the reason for this behavior. After facing this issue, I made sure that each token was only uploaded *once* to AWS SNS. When testing this, I realized that nevertheless I ended up with multiple endpoints with the *same* token - huh???
It turned out that these duplicated tokens resulted from *outdated* tokens being uploaded to AWS SNS. After creating an endpoint using an outdated token, SNS would automagically *revive* the endpoint by updating it with the *current* device token (which afaik is delivered back from GCM as a canonical ID once you try to send push messages to outdated tokens).

So e.g. uploading these (made-up) tokens and custom data

```
APA9...YFDw, {original_token: APA9...YFDw}
APA9...XaSd, {original_token: APA9...XaSd} <-- Assume this token is outdated
APA9...sVQa, {original_token: APA9...sVQa}
```

might result in something like this - i.e. different endpoints with identical tokens:

```
APA9...YFDw, {original_token: APA9...YFDw}, arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:4711:endpoint/GCM/myapp/daf64...5c204
APA9...YFDw, {original_token: APA9...XaSd}, arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:4711:endpoint/GCM/myapp/a980f...e3c82 <-- Duplicate token!
APA9...sVQa, {original_token: APA9...sVQa}, arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:4711:endpoint/GCM/myapp/14777...7d9ff
```

This scenario in turn seems to lead to above error on subsequent attempts to create endpoints using outdated tokens. On the hand, it seems correct that subsequent requests fail. On the other hand, intuitively I have the gut-feeling that the duplication of tokens that is taking place seems wrong, or at least difficult to handle. Maybe once SNS discovers that a token is outdated and needs to be changed, it could first check if there is already another endpoint existent with the same token...

I will research on this a bit more and see if I can find a way to handle this properly.

Cheers

Comment: I've just experienced the same issue that you did. For us, this means that we wont use amazon sns, since it's not able to create single URIs for our app on a specific device. It's actually easier for us to integrate with GCM, APNS in this case. By the way, you can force a new token by uninstalling the app, sending a push message while uninstalled, and then install it again. After registering the endpoint you will always get two ARNs with same token (after a while)

Comment: It is likely that endpoints/tokens expire over time. But when that happens you can update the attributes to enable them. A good token strategy is outlined here : http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx223MJB0XKV9RU/Mobile-token-management-with-Amazon-SNS

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, with the device reporting one token (outdated according to GCM) and the SNS retrieving/storing another.

We solved it by clearing the app cache on the device and reopening the app (which in our case, re-registered the device on the gcm service), generating the same token (not outdated) that SNS was attempting to push to.